# How do I kill animals inside my fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

There are 3 Elk Birds inside my fortress. How could I kill them?

I have a Cage trap in the entry (but they are in the 3rd floor) and a Battle Axe (but I don't know how to use it to kill them).

Comment: Did you try the usual ways? You know, crossbows, hammers, axes, traps, magma...

Comment: ^ Edited whit more info.

Comment: I edited your question. I believe that now is more clear what you want/have

Answer (score 2):

If you already have traps, the second method is to use a military. See this question: [How to set up a military](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74158/how-to-set-up-a-basic-military-in-dwarf-fortress).

You need to assign (using the military m screen) the dwarves with skill in the battle axe (carpentry works) or miners with pickaxes, to the military, and use the s squad interface to assign the elk birds as kill targets. Might also need to put the squad on alert.

And deactivate the squads etc afterwards. Getting drafted does have some negative thoughts for non military dwarfs though. But nothing a legendary dining area cannot fix.